# Mac bash script to start multiple Passenger standalone instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bash, passenger

I have some Rails projects on Ruby 1.9.x and some still on 1.8.7. I'm using RVM, and I'm using Phusion's preferred method of defaulting to 1.9 for my main Passenger and using the 1.8.7 (REE)-based projects in standalone mode.

I didn't feel like setting up vhosts for these, so I just bookmarked my dev sites with the localhost and port.

So, to restart, I created this bash script (answering my own question here to help any others) ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm answering my own question (per the FAQs) but answer is on hold. (This isn't working as smoothly as I hoped!)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty shell script.

In ~/start_rails.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Loop through directories of Passenger standalone sites
# and start, incrementing port each time
sites=( rails_site_1 rails_site_2 rails_site_3 )
port=3001

for dir in "${sites[@]}"
do
  echo "Switching to ${dir}"
  cd ~/Sites/$dir
  echo "Starting Passenger on port ${port}"
  passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p ${port} -d
  echo ""
  port=$((port+1))
done
```

Make sure the sites array appears in the order you bookmarked your ports. Call with start_rails.sh.